# How to pass an Array from Child component to Parent component using hooks in react

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project I am trying to pass a data from Child component to Parent component, But I don't know how to pass data from Child component to Parent component.

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Parent from './Parent/Parent';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-12'>
          <Parent></Parent>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is Parent.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Parent.css';
import Child from '../Child/Child';


const Parent = () => {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='one'>
                        <Child></Child>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Parent
```

This is Child.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Child.css';

const Child = () => {
    const students = ['Jasmine', 'Stella']
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Child
```

Comment: Well, passing data from Child to Parent is not a good idea. It would be better to pass a function from Parent to Child, which sets the array on the Parent side.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data from Child to Parent by calling a function passed from `Parent` with the data you want to send as a parameter - like an event handler callback.

Let's say if you want to send `students` of your Child component to Parent when you click on an element:

```js
const Parent = () => {
    const onUpdate = (data) => {
         // use the data
    };

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='one'>
                        <Child update={onUpdate}></Child>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```js
const Child = ({ update }) => {
    const students = ['Jasmine', 'Stella']

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                     <button click={() => update(students)} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But if you have to pass data between components nested deeply, you should consider to use `Redux` or `Context`.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, You have two easiest ways,

1. Use React context
2. Use React prop callback

I suggest you use the first way and here is an example of implementing the redux context feature into your app based on your question's codes.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-roentgen-mh217?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Redux is not used in the demo, you're using useContext hook.